# How to plot magnetic field lines in mathematica?

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica, visualization

[image]

I am preparing for the exams, and I have spent couple of days trying to solve the task, but without success. Can someone show me how I solve this? The result should look like this:

[image]

Comment: What kind of class assigns this as a question o_0!? Looks intense

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`StreamPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StreamPlot.html) or [`VectorPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/VectorPlot.html)
for 3D fields, there is no built-in command. However, you can use [`VectorPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/VectorPlot3D.html).
There is also a 3rd party code for 3D streamline plot that you can find [here](http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/computernotes/Mathematica/fieldLines3D.html).